# *pointer++ skips a char?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main() {

       char txt[] = "abcdefghij";
       char *pointer = &txt[1];

/* 1*/ printf("%p\n", txt);                     //0060FF21
/* 2*/ printf("%p\n", &pointer[0]);             //0060FF26
/* 3*/ printf("%c\n", *pointer);                //b
/* 4*/ printf("%p\n", pointer + 3);             //0060FF25
/* 5*/ printf("%c\n", *(pointer + 1 - 1));      //b
/* 6*/ printf("%p\n", ++pointer);               //0060FF23
/* 7*/ printf("%c\n", *++pointer);              //d
/* 8*/ printf("%p\n", pointer);                 //0060FF24
/* 9*/ printf("%c\n", --(*pointer));            //c
/*10*/ printf("test %c\n", *pointer);           //test c
/*11*/ printf("%c\n", *pointer++);              //c
/*12*/ printf("test %c\n", *pointer);           //test e <- why ? 
/*13*/ printf("%c\n", *(&pointer[1] - 1));      //e
/*14*/ printf("%c\n", *(pointer - 3));          //b
/*15*/ printf("%c\n", *pointer);                //e
/*16*/ printf("%c\n", pointer[-1]);             //c
/*17*/ printf("%c\n", (pointer + 1)[-1]);       //e
/*18*/ printf("%ld\n", pointer - txt);          //4

       return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

I wanted to ask, why the `*pointer` at `/*10*/ printf` is `c`, then the operation `*pointer++` (`/*11*/ printf`) prints `c` again, but then `*pointer` is `e`.

It makes no sense in my mind. I thought 
`*pointer++` means `*(pointer++)`, so `pointer++` would be the address of `d`, and `*(pointer++)` would print `d`.

What am I  doing wrong?

Comment: `++pointer` at 6th print changed pointer, not value

Comment: try printing out txt at the end of your code too and you should see why.

Comment: ah okay, so --(*pointer) doesent change the actual pointer? That would make sense. Thanks.

Comment: In particular, look at line 9.  Instead of asking why is line 12 printing an 'e', ask "why are lines 10 and 11 printing a 'c'?"

Comment: yea, pointer has the adress of d, but *pointer prints c ....so *pointer and pointer can be different ?

Comment: Try `printf( "\"%s\" %p=txt[%zu]=%c\n",txt,pointer,pointer-txt,*pointer);` between each line to breakdown the internal state of the variables.